# access 2000, sql server not in dropdown when linking

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have a windows 7 machine with access 2000 installed to support legacy apps. When I try to link a table "SQL Server" is not shown in the dropdown. I tried to link through code but the driver isn't present. I forgot how to fix this. I did a fresh install of Office 2000 selecting only access. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install MS SQL server connectivity tools